# Ubuntu 18.4 slows down after a few hours of usage; despite high available memory

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, performance, ram, visual-studio-code

I have been facing this issue daily, after about 10 hrs of usage Ubuntu becomes terrible slow, it lags a lot. Operations that take less than a second tend to take about 10 or more seconds. On the browser, the right click takes 3 or 4 seconds for the context menu to load. But I am surprised that the available memory remains high.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        3.3G        1.3G        160M        3.1G        3.9G
Swap:           42G        232M         42G
```

I use Visual Studio Code and Google Chrome mainly. After reboot I can run 20 tabs in Chrome without any lag, but by the day end having even 5 tabs are an issue.

Specification

```
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: X550JX 1.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.0.0-29-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 21 hours, 13 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2023 (dpkg), 253 (brew), 14 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 3.28.4 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: HighContrast 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adapta-Nokto-Eta [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Papirus-Dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-4720HQ (8) @ 3.600GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 2925MiB / 7862MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

[image: Nvidia Graphics Card is installed.]

## When Computer was slowing down

I was just watching a video on youtube.

```
$ free -m
# During this period the available memory/total memory *100% was almost 22%
```

```
$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15

Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
11.24   2264    58904   71  8.45    0.00
12.52   2410    86882   69  9.55    0.00
16.10   2788    112149  71  13.65   0.00
14.90   2369    92329   69  10.36   0.00
14.65   2168    77409   70  9.42    0.00
11.97   2103    79929   77  8.28    0.00
9.52    1960    63216   67  7.08    0.00
8.97    2336    60808   66  8.01    0.00
9.88    2580    46957   67  8.91    0.00
11.72   2602    55961   67  9.88    0.00
17.09   2361    79915   78  10.81   0.00
17.84   2741    83690   69  13.63   0.00
8.99    2303    48682   67  7.92    0.00
10.51   2340    61382   67  8.59    0.00
10.40   2308    53089   69  8.17    0.00
11.57   2109    72846   68  8.25    0.00
13.31   2308    62574   68  9.66    0.00
15.68   2119    89204   72  9.88    0.00
14.00   2292    67976   69  9.92    0.00
16.62   2478    82244   70  11.42   0.00
19.11   2430    90892   73  11.73   0.00
22.15   2461    89086   72  12.98   0.00
21.22   2421    83160   72  12.49   0.00
21.43   2428    91860   72  12.75   0.00
17.80   2442    65388   72  11.27   0.00
22.05   2572    77970   78  13.46   0.00
23.69   2688    67063   77  15.52   0.00
14.99   2542    65569   72  10.65   0.00
6.94    2427    39241   71  7.21    0.00
7.10    2130    36799   68  6.23    0.00
9.77    2265    45388   69  7.81    0.00
13.90   2446    62467   68  10.07   0.00
9.48    2495    42634   69  8.21    0.00
12.90   2591    59494   67  10.40   0.00
16.84   3012    49785   83  16.95   0.00
17.91   3244    51814   76  19.79   0.00
17.57   2950    54539   90  16.75   0.00
17.89   3147    55712   73  18.56   0.00
```

## When Computer was working fine

I was running a bash script for batch processing.

```
$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15

Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
15.07   2692    42570   76  12.74   0.00
17.27   2838    43539   89  15.39   0.00
18.77   2830    48453   77  15.95   0.00
16.38   2866    45129   90  14.79   0.00
20.88   2975    58471   94  18.65   0.00
18.35   3038    51718   78  17.96   0.00
10.61   2560    31928   81  9.53    0.00
4.83    1691    19197   70  4.06    0.00
7.77    1556    27624   68  4.93    0.00
6.42    1751    20653   80  5.05    0.00
15.13   2742    38587   69  14.11   0.00
20.14   2962    51125   88  18.20   0.00
22.33   3078    50598   86  19.84   0.00
20.85   2873    64946   85  17.27   0.00
15.51   2758    45702   87  13.56   0.00
13.59   2691    40346   85  12.79   0.00
16.53   2814    44112   85  15.33   0.00
19.50   2969    47386   78  17.68   0.00
24.29   3181    55619   80  21.42   0.00
19.83   3012    48117   84  17.54   0.00
17.39   2894    46105   76  15.95   0.00
13.62   2733    39877   79  12.79   0.00
16.91   2857    44110   77  15.68   0.00
15.77   2939    37861   82  15.40   0.00
13.42   2680    36564   75  12.59   0.00
8.06    1998    26089   71  6.17    0.00
6.30    2230    21428   69  5.66    0.00
9.70    2006    30448   70  6.40    0.00
17.36   2812    46268   75  15.55   0.00
21.81   3095    49851   86  20.15   0.00
18.58   2854    49990   87  16.71   0.00
17.49   2771    50942   84  15.14   0.00
20.62   2989    48209   85  18.16   0.00
17.46   2797    41752   83  15.45   0.00
17.47   2823    44291   79  15.38   0.00
21.57   3032    47860   84  18.86   0.00
21.33   3069    66774   97  19.70   0.00
27.15   3282    71376   90  26.12   0.00
16.62   2735    48096   81  14.64   0.00
15.88   2761    47882   90  13.73   0.00
27.55   3122    66182   81  22.79   0.00
15.76   2818    45970   75  14.23   0.00
4.25    1534    17575   71  3.57    0.00
3.33    1498    14550   68  3.26    0.00
10.71   2276    36448   73  8.19    0.00
15.65   2746    42236   71  14.19   0.00
16.02   2780    41543   79  14.67   0.00
15.52   2731    40590   70  14.07   0.00
15.51   2795    41968   85  14.69   0.00
16.97   2803    43944   78  15.16   0.00
17.43   2852    48317   80  16.01   0.00
19.63   2908    53122   74  17.34   0.00
8.79    2413    35149   70  7.09    0.00
7.60    2095    29110   68  6.20    0.00
3.43    1550    15492   66  3.46    0.00
3.90    1648    16872   63  3.56    0.00
4.16    1555    17133   63  3.63    0.00
6.84    2000    23774   62  5.48    0.00
12.35   2658    37123   80  10.73   0.00
9.18    2130    31543   63  6.80    0.00
```

### Attachments

- `cat /var/log/kern.log`: http://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/KernLog.html,
- `cat /var/log/syslog`: http://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/SysLog.html
- `journalctl`: https://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/JournalCtl.html

## Notes from Intel:

According to Intel for my processor Thermal Design Power  is  47 Watts. Refer: [Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.60 GHz) Product Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78934/intel-core-i7-4720hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html)

**According to Intel**: Thermal Design Power (TDP) represents the average power, in watts, the processor dissipates when operating at Base Frequency with all cores active under an Intel-defined, high-complexity workload. Refer to Datasheet for thermal solution requirements.

Comment: You have not given us much to go on.There are typical things I look for upon slowdown, but I have no idea in your case, so my suggestion might be a waste of time: Your processor is capable of running tubostat (linux-tools-common package). Run this command always in a terminal `sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. and do you observe anything just prior to and/or after the slow down?

Comment: @DougSmythies What additional information would be helpful  to resolve the issue?

Comment: The turbostat output would be enough for me to either say "not this" or, potentially, the suggest the next investigation step.

Comment: @DougSmythies I have added the data. Another question is that  GFXWatt remains zero? Is this ok, even though I have installed Nvidia Graphics Card?

Comment: You processor is awfully hot, given such a light load. It might be that a thermal event gets triggered causing the slow down. GFXWatts of 0 simply means you are not using the intel built in graphics stuff, which you did mention. Are there any temperature type messages in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @DougSmythies Please see: https://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/KernLog.html, https://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/SysLog.html . Also I am using Laptop cooling pad.

Comment: Gosh. You have a significant thermal problem. However, it doesn't seem to be from your processor itself (I might be wrong). Maybe your graphics card or lack of air or...

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the acceptable range of pkg temperature? Could you also tell us so that we can have some understanding of the system? Also please see: https://agarwal-nikhil.gitlab.io/gist/SlowDown/JournalCtl.html. According to Intel for my processor Thermal Design Power  is  47 Watts. Refer: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78934/intel-core-i7-4720hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html

Comment: run turbostat without the --quiet option, and it will tell you the limits. Myself, I never like my processor package temperature to go above 80 degrees or so, and it doesn't.TDP of 47 watts doesn't mean the processor will not get too hot, you still have to manage the waste heat. You need to find the actual heat source and/or look at your cooling and/or your thermal conducting paste between your processor and your heat sink.

Comment: @DougSmythies It says `cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x02641000 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x882b080a (57 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (100 C, 100 C)`

Comment: In my case on 18.04, it is `orca` that somewhat slows down gui user interface reaction time.